# I am trying to update column where the filter is a string in Laravel 8

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I tried:

```
Acessos::where('user_id',$uid)->where('routes','=',$routes )->update(['qtd_acessos' => 'qtd_acessos + 1'] );
```

the Error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value:
> 'qtd_acessos + 1' for column 'qtd_acessos' at row 2 (SQL: update
> `acessos` set `qtd_acessos` = qtd_acessos + 1 where `user_id` = 3 and
> `routes` = /home)

the question is: How to put the quotes in the routes column using eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the increment method instead of update.

You can find the documantetion about it here: [Database query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#increment-and-decrement)